# Center form on screen during runtime

Tags: vb.net

I'm using `vb.net`, and what I have in mind is on clicking a button, the current form will expand and it will be centered on screen.

I've figured out how to expand the form, but I can't center it on screen.

I've tried using this code but it's not what I wanted to get.

```
Dim Width As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
Dim Height As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height

Me.Location = New Point(Height / 2, Width / 2)
```

or otherwise: `Me.Location = New Point(Width / 2, Height/ 2)`

even tried this: `Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Center`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.CentreToScreen()`

Like this:

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(400, 650)
    Me.CenterToScreen()
End Sub
```

Comment: didn't work :( it only expanded my form, and stayed on its place.

Comment: how do you want to expand it?

Comment: here's my code on expanding: 'Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(400, 650)' while the original form is 400 x 450 so only its length will expand